# graphics_qt_qpainter.moc:13

Tags: qt4

```
        Hi all, 

        i'm getting the following error while building navit
```

In file included from graphics_qt_qpainter.cpp:194:
     graphics_qt_qpainter.moc:13: fatal error: private/qucomextra_p.h: No such file or directory
     compilation terminated.

make[6]: *** [graphics_qt_qpainter.lo] Error 1
    make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/user/navit-0.2.0/navit/graphics/qt_qpainter'
        make[5]: *** [all] Error 2...

can anyone help me out in solving this error?

Answer (score 1):

**Richard Genoud** posted this at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kbuild.devel/5675

Works for me in Debian, should do for Ubuntu and other Debian derivatives, at least.

------------------- 8< -------------------------

this is due to moc which points by default to /usr/bin/moc-qt3

just make it point to moc-qt4 :

sudo update-alternatives --config moc

then make distclean, make xconfig.